# A second matlab figure based on pixel coordinate data on the first figure

Tags: matlab

I have a `imagesc` image in which each pixel represent a data vector. The image itself is from a data cube squeezed into 2D matrix. I can use `impixelinfo` to navigate through the image and get pixel coordinates when inquiring the image. The code to execute this is below,

```
load data.mat; % data cube of size 512x256x12000
figure; imagesc(squeeze(mean(abs(data),3)))
axis equal; colormap jet;
impixelinfo
```

What I want to do is to be able to plot the underlying data vector (laying into the 3rd dimension) in a second figure using the pixel coordinates. This second figure should update automatically when I move the cursor in the image.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please add a [mcve] of your code, otherwise we're grasping at straws in a pitch-black cave.

Comment: You can do it with WindowButtonMotionFcn callback

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, I found a solution with `ButtonDownFcn` and posting it here for folks out there with a similar problem.

```
x = (-10:10); y = x; z = x;
[mx, my, mz] = ndgrid(x,y,z)
r = sqrt(mx.^2 + my.^2 + mz.^2);
figure;
imagesc(squeeze(r(:,:,1)),'ButtonDownFcn', {@test_func,r});
```

with the following function

```
function test_func(hObject, eventdata, r);
P = get(gca,'CurrentPoint');
X = round(P(1,1));Y = round(P(1,2));
figure;plot(squeeze(r(X,Y,:)));
end
```